# Linux sys_clone. Free'ing stack memory

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, clone

I am trying to implement a version of `pthread_create` just for the heck of it using the `clone()` system call. I am curious as to how `pthread` **free**'s the stack memory after the thread has exited. This is what I have tried:

```
struct ThreadInfo{...}

void ThreadPrint(){...}

void HandleThread(args){
ThreadInfo* info = (cast here)args;

info->callfunction;

free(info->stack)
}


void CreateThread(callfunction){

ThreadInfo info = {};
info.stack = //alloc stack
info.callfunction = callfunction;

clone(HandleThread,...,&info)

}

int main(){
CreateThread(ThreadPrint);
}
```

This method doesn't work because the process still needs to use its stack during the `free()` function call in `HandleThread`. It's probably because the return address is lost when the stack is free'd and free cannot return anymore so maybe using a raw system call might work. Other than that I am not sure how I to free the thread's stack without using a separate process.

EDIT: To those who are interested, this is the system call I made to have the thread free its own stack.

```
 __asm__ volatile (
            "mov $11,%%rax\n"  //call munmap
             "mov %[addr],%%rdi\n"
             "mov %[len],%%rsi\n"
             "syscall\n"
            "xor %%rdi,%%rdi\n"
            "mov $60,%%rax\n"//manually call exit
             "syscall\n":: [addr] "g" (info->stack), [len] "g" (info->stacksize)
             );
```

As far as I know, you have to use inline assembly. Using the C function wrapper will leave the thread with no where to return to. If anyone has a better solution, I would love to hear it. Better yet, if anyone knows the internals of the pthread library, would love to hear that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't free the stack in the thread you just created. The parent process ie your main thread owns the stack and it would free it when the thread returns.

The man page has an example of using clone including creating the stack properly.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone

You need to setup a data structure that tracks the threads along with their stacks so when you test to see if the child is still alive or get a signal that it's dead you can cleanup.

Comment: Well....I just did a raw system call to munmap and it solved my problem. It was like I thought, the C call to munmap has no access to the return address on the deallocated stack. Using a raw system call   doesn't need a return address. What are the advantages of using a separate data structure? Wouldn't I need a separate process to manage the dead threads if that was the case?

Comment: Yes. You'd normally manage the threads from the parent. That means the parent needs to keep track of them using the `pid` it gets from the clone call. Look at what the guy has done here... https://github.com/adamhooper/code-from-adamhoopers-school-days/blob/master/mcgill-se/ECSE427/ass2/YAKThreads.c

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll look into it deeper when I have the time. However, doesn't this mean that the user has to explicitly delete the thread themselves? Nothing wrong with that, but if I remember correctly that is not the case in pthreads, no?

Comment: Have a look at pthread_exit and pthread_join to see what they're doing. Remember you're the one writing the a pthread like library, your users might not have to `free` anything but that does not mean you don't have to as part of your API.

Comment: Yeah, I just downloaded the source code of pthreads a few days ago. Gonna take a while it's huge. It's just that from what I understand of pthreads, the user does not have to explicitly call pthread_exit and even if they do, it is the thread that actually calls the function, assuming the function handles clean up. pthread_join only takes care of zombie processes so it is not really relevant to the stack clean up as far as I know. And yes, my implementation does auto free its memory on exit by explicitly calling the system call to do so instead of using the C function wrapper which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Managing thread stacks is done by glibc The library uses `mmap` to allocate thread stacks and `munmap` to free them.

Recall that threads can be joinable or detached.

For a joinable thread, deallocating all of its resources can be deferred until `pthread_join` is called on it. The threading library can deallocate its stack at that time (or mark it free for re-use).

When a detached thread terminates, even if the library isn't notified of this, it will eventually hunt down the unused stack and recycle it.

Comment: Let me know if it would help to have exact references into the Glibc source tree.